# Unable to access the properties to and userProfile.displayName

Tags: outlook-web-addins

The following calls seem to be returning empty results when opening a mail hosted in a mailbox on Exchange WebServer 2013 15.0.1473.4003

```
office.context.mailbox.userProfile
office.context.mailbox.item.to
```

- Exchange WebServer 2013 15.0.1473

**Sample of Clients tested**

Mac | Outlook 16.29 (190908.02) | Fail

Mac | Outlook 16.16.14 (190909) | Success

Mac | Outlook 16.16.13 (190811) | Success

Mac | Outlook 16.29 (190908.02) | Success

PC | Outlook 16.0.12026.20264 | Success

UPDATED: The issue is appearing for only one single client (Outlook 16.29 - 190908.02) but is working fine for another user with the same version.

Comment: You have mentioned its failing on Mac | Outlook 16.29 (190908.02) but in fourth line for the same build you mentioned it as success. Can you please clarify which platform and build you are facing this issue?

Comment: I am sorry I corrected the wording of the question. The issue is happening for only one single client.

Comment: Are you able to repro the issue in the later builds also?

Comment: Please let us know if this issue is reproducible with latest build available from https://macadmins.software/